# How to send post/get json values (html) to an API?

Tags: javascript, html, json

New into Javascript/HTML. So please be easy on me!

What I have done in my script right now is that I have created a form with different value options where a user can input their inputs. After a user hits submit. I have done a function that checks if one of the values actually have a value, if not then retry. If there is a value then we continue and right now I have made a simple thing where I save the value into a json format.

```
<script src="FileSaver.js"></script>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  var inpObj = document.getElementById("namn");
  if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) {
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Tack för beställning";

    var data = {'name': name.value, 'flask': flask.value, 'kyckling': kyckling.value, 'anka': anka.value, 'kalkon': kalkon.value, 'leverans': leverans.value, 'ovrigt':ovrigt.value}
    var json = JSON.stringify(data)
    var blob = new Blob([json],{type:"application/json"});
    saveAs(blob,"helloworld.json");
  } 
} 

</script>
```

What I want to do now is that I want to send the value `var data` to a POST/GET Api which will read the json format and then save the file to a json (It is through a C# server). However I have tried to search around and I haven't really found a way how to send values (JSON) to an API.

I would appreciate all kind of help!

Full HTML + Javascript + [Filesaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Hello</title>

  <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/linericon/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/nice-select/nice-select.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ================ header section start ================= -->    
    <header class="header_area">
    <div class="header-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
          <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt="" title="" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</header>
<!-- ================ header section end ================= -->  

<main class="site-main">


  <!-- ================ start banner area ================= --> 
  <section class="home-banner-area" id="home">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="home-banner">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1>handlingslist</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- ================ end banner area ================= -->


  <!-- ================ start banner form ================= --> 
  <form class="form-search form-search-position">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FormControlSelect1">Handlingslist Namn</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="namn" type="text" placeholder="Skriv in namn.." required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Fläsk</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="flask">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Kyckling</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="kyckling">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Anka</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="anka">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Kalkon</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="kalkon">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-select-custom">
              <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Leverans</label>
              <select name="" id="leverans">
                <option value="8 AM">8:00</option>
                <option value="12 PM">12:00</option>
                <option value="6 PM">18:00</option>
                <option value="9 PM">21:00</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">För övriga information, vänligen och informera...</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="ovrigt" type="text" placeholder="Enter your keywords..">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm gutters-19">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="button button-form" id="toggle" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit">Beställning</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- ================ end banner form ================= --> 


</main>



<!-- ================ start footer Area ================= -->
<footer class="footer-area section-gap">
  <p class="col-md-15 text-center">
  Copyright &copy; 2019 All rights reserved | Made by Thrill</a>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
<!-- ================ End footer Area ================= -->

<script src="FileSaver.js"></script>

    <script>

  function myFunction() {
    var inpObj = document.getElementById("namn");
    if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) {
      document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("toggle").innerHTML = "Tack för beställning";

      var data = {'name': test.value, 'flask': flask.value, 'kyckling': kyckling.value, 'anka': anka.value, 'kalkon': kalkon.value, 'leverans': leverans.value, 'ovrigt':ovrigt.value}
      var json = JSON.stringify(data)
      var blob = new Blob([json],{type:"application/json"});
      saveAs(blob,"helloworld.json");

      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

    } 
  } 

</script>

<script src="vendors/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/superfish.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/nice-select/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/mail-script.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to be able to send the value `var data` to an API. *I believe....*

Comment: Sending post/get requests to an API is called `AJAX` requests. maybe this helps you finding your solution.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Your snippet is missing some information, such as definition of `saveAs`. If `saveAs` is what you want help with implementing, then that's unclear. Please provide the markup (HTML) so we can know how the form is submitted and what kind of form it is.

Comment: @amn There we go. I have no updated the script! :)

Comment: Instead of using stringify then convert string to blob send json object (varable 'data') directly to api

Comment: @VikasSonichya Hello! Thanks for the information. The problem is I am not sure how to send directly to an API from here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are tring to do a rest call, there are lot of way to do this, if you dont want to use nay library (like jquery) you can use `fetch` api

```
fetch(`Your_server_url`, {
    method: "POST", //OR GET
    mode: "cors", // If your page and your API server is in differnet location

    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",// because you are sending JSON data
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // your tata 
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

You can learn about fetch [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: I have done a small update on the code (The long one) and I am not sure if I have done it correct now but please take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an `Ajax` example:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {varRecibed:varSended},
    type: "POST",
    url: "the-url-api",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(){
        //Action before send info
    },
    success: function(data){
        //When api finish, data is the returning info from the api.
        console.log(data);      
    }
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

*@amn* is right, **you need to include** the `jQuery library` to use `$.ajax` https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Hey Roy! Thanks for the answer. This might be dumb question but am I able to paste this code directly after the row `saveAs(blob,"helloworld.json");` in my code? and I assume also in your code line `data: {varRecibed:varSended}` is where I enter the data of json that I have created `var data = {'name': test.value, 'flask': flask.value, 'kyckling': kyckling.value, 'anka': anka.value, 'kalkon': kalkon.value, 'leverans': leverans.value, 'ovrigt':ovrigt.value}` ?

Comment: Yep, just change the `url: "the-url-api"` and `data: data` in case that you already set the `var data = {'name': test.value, 'flask': flask.value, 'kyckling': kyckling.value, 'anka': anka.value, 'kalkon': kalkon.value, 'leverans': leverans.value, 'ovrigt':ovrigt.value}`

Comment: Right! lets say now that I would copy this code. Would I be able to post it right after the line `saveAs(blob,"helloworld.json");` or do I need to do a new function for it?

Comment: Alright awesome! Thanks alot! I think I might know what to do now.

Comment: If you are going to teach people how to use JQuery, you may want to specify that your snippet requires the library. It's isn't implied by referencing JQuery documentation on the `ajax` call.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function to execute a POST to the server:

```
function post (path, data) {
  return window.fetch(path, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
```

Then you call this function like this:

```
post('/url', {data, data1});
```